Adding two floating joints to the same body
I would like to have a system where a part can be transferred from one suction gripper into another suction gripper. I've implemented a single suction gripper, and it works great. It attaches the part to the end effector's link.
def add_suction_joint(plant: MultibodyPlant) -> QuaternionFloatingJoint:
    suction_body = plant.GetBodyByName("combo_end_effector_link")

    object_id = plant.GetModelInstanceByName("part1")
    object_body = plant.GetBodyByName("part1_link", object_id)
    suction_joint = plant.AddJoint(
        QuaternionFloatingJoint(
            "suction_joint",
            suction_body.body_frame(),
            object_body.body_frame(),
        ),
    )

    translation = [0.03, 0, 0.34]
    rotation = RollPitchYaw(
        0,
        np.pi / 2,
        0,
    ).ToQuaternion()  # This rotation makes the gripper oriented along the axis of the final joint
    suction_to_object = RigidTransform(rotation, translation)

    suction_joint.SetDefaultPose(suction_to_object)

However, if I try to add a section joint, I get an error
Code:
plant.AddJoint(
        QuaternionFloatingJoint(
            "gripper_2_joint",
            plant.GetBodyByName("gripper_2_link").body_frame(),
            object_body.body_frame(),
        ),
    )

Error:
RuntimeError: When creating a model, an attempt was made to add two inboard joints to the same rigid body; this is not allowed. One possible cause might be attempting to weld a robot to World somewhere other than its base rigid body; see Drake issue #17429 for discussion and work-arounds, e.g., reversing some joint parent/child directions. Another possible cause might be attempting to form a kinematic loop using joints; to create a loop, consider using a LinearBushingRollPitchYaw instead of a joint.

This error makes sense; as you wouldn't want two suction joints to be turned on at a time. However, I would like some way of making the part unlock from the first gripper and then lock to the second gripper.
Alternatively, if there's any way to make the part temporarily welded to a certain frame/position, that could work too.
The second gripper is static so if I could just set the part to stay in a position while the second gripper is "enabled", that is sufficient. plant.SetFreeBodyPose doesn't work because physics still applies to the part, so even if I set a pose, the part could fall over. Or perhaps there's a way to use SetFreeBodyPose and turn off physics for a part.

Modeling suction is a common request; we should definitely make it easier for folks to do this. You can find a discussion (and tracking of the status) in this issue.
The long-term solution is to model the forces that the suction produces; if you want it to take a suction command as input then it could be implemented like the Propeller class.
The short-term solution is to lock and unlock joints -- it sounds like you are pursuing this approach already -- but just in case I do have an example notebook linked from this issue comment. But as you correctly point out, this approach will get more difficult (and considerably less elegant) if you have two suction grippers; because you will now have a kinematic loop. However, it can be made to work.
I think you would want to make a kinematic tree like this:

arm1 w/ suction 1

quaternion floating joint

object 1


quaternion floating joint

object 2




arm2 w/ suction 2

quaternion floating joint

dummy object 1 (w/ no mass nor geometry)


quaternion floating joint

dummy object 2 (w/ no mass nor geometry)





then you would use MultibodyPlant::AddWeldConstraint to weld the dummy objects to the real objects. (It would be slightly more elegant to put half of the mass on each of the copies of the body, but I think our solver should be ok with the zero mass on the dummy object version.)
